# Count number of times a word is found in txt file

Tags: c++, fstream

Currently have this simple code written, trying to figure out why it's not counting specific words every time.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t = 0;
    int a1 = 0;
    string a[100];
    ifstream food;

    food.open("food.txt");

    if (food.fail())
    {
        cout << "File can't open" << endl;

    }

    else
        cout << "File successfully opened" << endl;

    int i = 0;

    while (!food.eof())
    {
        // Tomato
        food >> a[i];
        if (a[i] == "tomato")
        {
            t = t + 1;
        }
        i++;

        // Apple
        food >> a[i];
        if (a[i] == "apple")
        {
            a1 = a1 + 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    cout << "Amount of Tomatos: " << t << endl;
    cout << "Amount of Apples: " << a1 << endl;
}
```

**The text file I'm using:**

```
apple
apple
tomato
apple
tomato
tomato
```

**The output:**

```
File successfully opened
Amount of Tomatoes: 2
Amount of Apples: 2
```

The purpose is to find the amount of each food found in the list. I'm currently only using two kinds of food but will have many more.

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: i suggest to read it to your rubber duck. It should raise an eyebrow or two once you reach the "I read one food, if its an apple I increment the apple counter, then I read the next food, if its a tomato, I increment the tomato counter, then I repeat" part...

Comment: After re-looking at it and looking at other comments, I realized what I was doing wrong with the if and else statements. Does sound odd now that I realize my mistake.

Comment: Since the quantity of words is unknown at run-time, use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of an array.  Arrays can overflow.  Large arrays may be a waste of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

- using `eof()` in a loop incorrectly.  You can't check `eof()` before performing a read operation first.
- using an array without bounds checking.  For that matter, you don't need an array at all.
- skipping words, which is why you are not counting everything you are expecting.  Let's take the very first line, `apple`. Since it is not a `"tomato"`, you skip it and read the next word in the file, which is `"apple"`, so you count it.  But you didn't count the 1st `apple` at all.

You need to do something more like this instead:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int tomatoes = 0;
  int apples = 0;
  string s;
  ifstream food;

  food.open("food.txt");

  if (!food.is_open())
  {
    cout << "File can't open" << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  cout << "File successfully opened" << endl;

  while (food >> s)
  {
    // Tomato
    if (s == "tomato")
        ++tomatoes;

    // Apple
    else if (s == "apple")
        ++apples;
  }

  cout << "Amount of Tomatos: " << tomatoes << endl;
  cout << "Amount of Apples: " << apples << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, as @user463035818 mentioned in comments, you can use a `std::map` instead:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  map<string, int> foods;
  string s;
  ifstream food;

  food.open("food.txt");

  if (!food.is_open())
  {
    cout << "File can't open" << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  cout << "File successfully opened" << endl;

  while (food >> s) {
    foods[s]++;
  }

  for (map<string, int>::iterator iter = foods.begin(); iter != foods.end(); ++iter) {
      cout << "Amount of " << iter->first << ": " << iter->second << endl;
  }

  /* or, if you are using C++11 or later...
  for (auto &item : foods) {
      cout << "Amount of " << item.first << ": " << item.second << endl;
  }
  */

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really see where I over did a few things and did notice the if and else if was very important. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Addendum: Also note how Remy used variable names that described what they counted. This is very helpful in reducing bugs, as it's easier to to see where you accidentally used `apples` in place of `tomatoes` than `t` and `a1`. In addition you spend less time looking up the meaning of `t` and `a1` when debugging.

Comment: @user4581301 I suppose yes, especially since I'm still fairly new to C++. Wasn't sure if using this website would help me understand things easier, but I'm confident in that now.